# Significance of SID, Host and Port - Database Connection

Tags: oracle

I have a simple question reg database connection parameters

- Host
- Port
- SID.

AFAIK, a single instance uses a single port on a host, i.e. for a host, there would be only one instance active on the port. If that is true, the set of host and port can uniquelty identify a single instance to connect to, then why do we need SID ?

Answer (score 4):

Two instances can use the same listener, listening on the same port.

Hence the need for the SID.

Answer (score 3):

One listener, running on a single host on a single port, can make available multiple SIDs from that single port.

That's why the parameter in the configuration is called "SID_LIST_LISTENER" -- it's a LIST of SIDs.